# How do you invert the scroll-to-zoom in the storyboards for Xcode?

Tags: macos, scrolling, xcode

I have inverted the scrolling on my Mac such that I find it more comfortable. However, this of course also inverted the scrolling on my storyboards which I find uncomfortable. Is there a way to invert the scrolling on just the storyboards such that I don't have to choose between being comfortable in the storyboard or being comfortable while programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a third-party solution, one that can switch on a per-app basis.

Specific product recommendations are off topic, but as there are really only two that can do this, I'll let you see which may suit you best - [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) or 
[USB Overdrive](https://www.usboverdrive.com). Both can do a whole lot more than simply switch natural scroll on & off.